# How to Retrieve database fields in IF statement in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to read my database field in my 2nd `IF` condition or `ElseIf` and it seems not working right. it's like i'm trying to validate if a certain student has the same position in a partylist or a student is already in another partylist and cannot run on other partylist.

code:

```
cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' AND cparty='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Position in that partylist already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    ElseIf dr("cfname") = TextBox2.Text And dr("cmname") = TextBox3.Text And dr("clname") = TextBox4.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Student is currently in another partylist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        'Success'
Endif
```

**UPDATE**

i did something like this

`cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' AND cparty='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'; SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cfname='" & TextBox2.Text & "' AND cmname='" & TextBox3.Text & "' AND clname='" & TextBox4.Text & "' "`

```
    If dr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Position in that partylist already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    dr.NextResult()
    End If
    If dr.HasRows Then
        MessageBox.Show("Student is currently in another position", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End If
```

its working right, but another thing is when i trigger the first `IF` and the 2nd `IF` also triggers, i know that will happen but i don't know what to do, if i'll make the 2nd `IF` into `ElseIf` then it's not doing what i wanted to do. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cpos='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' AND cparty='" & ComboBox2.Text & "'; SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE cfname='" & TextBox2.Text & "' AND cmname='" & TextBox3.Text & "' AND clname='" & TextBox4.Text & "' "
```

this was just the answer, whew!

```
If dr.HasRows Then
    MessageBox.Show("Position in that partylist already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
ElseIF dr.NexResult Then
    MessageBox.Show("Student is currently in another position", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End If
```

Comment: friendly word of advice: **any** answer which uses SQL concatenation rather than SQL Parameters runs the risk of getting heavily downvoted.  It is a very bad, dangerous practice. It might work "ok" for your purposes, but SO answers are supposed to represent a *good* way to do something for *anyone* with a similar problem in the future.